# Child window stops being modal after minimalization

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have simple WPF app, main window, and button, that on click creates a new modal child 
 window via my window manager:

```
class WindowManager : IWindowManager
    {       
        public void AddNewViewWindow()
        {
            var someWindow = new AddNewView();
            someWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false; 
            someWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            someWindow.ShowDialog();            
        }
    }
```

MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="LogView.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Title="{Binding Title}" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentRegion" />
            <Button Name="AddNewControl" Content="Add New Control" Command="{Binding AddNewViewCommand}" Margin="10">
                <Button.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Button.Background>               
            </Button>
            <CheckBox Name="EditMode" Content="Edit mode" IsChecked="{Binding EditModeEnabled}" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>        
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ModalChildWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="LogView.Views.AddNewView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogView.Views"
        xmlns:prism ="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AddNewView" Height="450" Width="800">
    <StackPanel>

    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding DeviceSets}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"   ItemsSource="{Binding Registers}">
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name}">
                            </TextBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

I am also using Prism, my bootstrapper:

```
class Bootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
    {
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
    }

    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {            
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();                                 
        RegisterTypeIfMissing(typeof(IWindowManager), typeof(WindowManager), true);           
    }

    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        var moduleCatalog = (ModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog;
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(WebSocketClientModule));            
    }
}
```

Now, I am experiencing this strange behavior:

When I click the button, modal child window shows up. Everything is fine, I can't click on parent(MainWindow) window. Then, if I minimalize this child modal window, and then bring it back on, the child window stops being modal. I can click on MainWindow and create a second modal window ( the first one is still visible). What is even weird, the second modal window is truly modal, when I minimalize it, bring it on I cannot click on the parent window. If I close the second modal window, I can create it again.
Greetings

Comment: That is strange and is not expected! It would be helpful if you can paste XAML of both Childwindow  and ParentWindow. determining from this piece of code is difficult.

Comment: Are you positive that Application.Current.MainWindow is the same window as the one containing the button? What happens when you leave out the assignment of the Owner?

Comment: Xaml code Added. @grepfruit, I have only one MainWindow in my app, so it should be it. But how can i be sure. To create MainWIndow I am using Prism  Boostrapper  (   protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
        {
            return Container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
        })

Comment: You can check the MainWindow value by adding breakpoint .e.g after the assignment to Owner. As for the Prism init, there a second step mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/gg430868(v=pandp.40)) - overriding InitializeShell to set created shell as the MainWindow.

Comment: If  I levae out setting the owner, the behavior is the same. I can create  the second modal window, but not the third

Comment: I have just confirmed that the onwer is mainwindow. Also I added my bootstrapper code

Comment: Just one last idea: Are you positive that there isn't a second instance of the MainWindow being opened? E.g. by having something like 'StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"' in the App.xaml.cs . The other instance would be shown through the Boostrapper code. Minimizing the first opened AddNewView window would leave the other Main Window visible and allow you to click the button a second time.

Comment: Nope, I am printing message in MainWindowViewModel costructor and I can see it only once.

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant, but if I minimalize child windows, they end up above windows task bar :[link](https://ibb.co/cCCXOJ)

Comment: I created WPF app, only with two windows:main window with button, and some other windows that will show up upon button click.  In code behind of MainWindow: private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var addNewViewWindow = new TestWindow();
            addNewViewWindow.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            addNewViewWindow.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;           
            addNewViewWindow.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            addNewViewWindow.ShowDialog();
        }   The window behaviour is still the same